# Angular Password Strength Extension show error if strength not 100

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am actually tired of trying things to achieve a very simple thing. I got an reactive form and just want to show an error if the password strength is not 100, so does not fulfill all the requirements.

I can directly access the the strength with `passwordComponent.strength` and it changes dynamically if I display it e.g. as div in my form. The error just gets shown when the input field is empty. As soon as one character is in the inputfield no error is shown.

```html
 <mat-button-toggle #toggleDetails class="requirements" tabindex="-1"
   matTooltip="{{ 'REGISTRATION.PASSWORDREQUIREMENTS' | translate }}" matTooltipClass="tooltip"
   matTooltipPosition="below" [matTooltipShowDelay]="globals.showDelay.value"
   [matTooltipHideDelay]="globals.hideDelay.value">
   <mat-icon *ngIf="toggleDetails.checked">done_all</mat-icon>
   <mat-icon *ngIf="!toggleDetails.checked">done</mat-icon>
 </mat-button-toggle>

 <mat-form-field class="field-sizing">
   <input matInput (keydown)="onKeyDownSpace($event)" [maxlength]="globals.maxPasswordLength" required
     [type]="globals.hidePassword ? 'password' : 'text'"
     placeholder="{{ 'REGISTRATION.PASSWORD' | translate }}" #password formControlName="password"
     [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.password.touched && f.password.errors }" />
   <button tabindex="-1" mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="globals.hidePassword = !globals.hidePassword"
     [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="globals.hidePassword">
     <mat-icon>{{globals.hidePassword ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
   </button>
   <mat-hint style="color: red" *ngIf="capslockOn && f.password.touched" align="start" aria-live="polite">
     <strong>{{ 'CAPSLOCK' | translate }}</strong>
   </mat-hint>
   <mat-hint align="end" aria-live="polite">
     {{password.value.length}} / {{globals.maxPasswordLength}}
   </mat-hint>
   <mat-error class="invalid-feedback"
     *ngIf="f.password.touched && f.password.errors && f.password.errors.required">
     {{ 'REGISTRATION.PASSWORD' | translate }} {{ 'VALIDATION.REQUIRED' | translate }}
   </mat-error>
   <mat-error *ngIf="passwordComponent.strength !== 100">
     Weak
   </mat-error>

 </mat-form-field>

 <div>
   <p>Password's strength = {{passwordComponent.strength}} %100</p>
 </div>

 <div class="password-strength">
   <mat-password-strength #passwordComponent [min]="globals.minPasswordLength" [password]="password.value">
   </mat-password-strength>

   <mat-password-strength-info tabindex="-1" *ngIf="toggleDetails.checked" [enableScoreInfo]="true"
     [passwordComponent]="passwordComponent" [lowerCaseCriteriaMsg]="'LOWER_CASE_CRITERIA_MSG' | translate"
     [upperCaseCriteriaMsg]="'UPPER_CASE_CRITERIA_MSG'| translate"
     [digitsCriteriaMsg]="'DIGITS_CRITERIA_MSG'| translate"
     [specialCharsCriteriaMsg]="'SPECIAL_CHARS_CRITERIA_MSG' | translate"
     [minCharsCriteriaMsg]="'MIN_CHARS_CRITERIA_MSG' | translate">
   </mat-password-strength-info>
 </div>
```

My simple idea was just to but there a `*ngIf` and check if the strength is 100 or not and also if this would work that the field is touched, what would be very simple but that does not work. The `formControl` for that field just includes the `required` validator.

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz or at least post your components code and module code here?

Comment: What exactly do you need? I don't get why you need it. That's why I didn't added that. It would be too much code.

Comment: I think you could try `<mat-error *ngIf="passwordComponent.touched && passwordComponent.strength !== 100">` I think this will work.

Comment: @Shorbagy no. That is the strange thing. If the strength is something different then 0 then never an error appears and I have really no idea why because I can see the strength is 20 and the if-Statement should work.

Comment: @CptDayDreamer I want a minimum reproducible example. You don't get "why I need it?" Maybe because you haven't followed the Stackoverflow guidelines of posting a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Without that example, you're assuming that the issue is in your markup, which may be the case, but if you knew what/where the issue was, you wouldn't be asking us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you case you should use custom validator which is correct way *ngIF checks the password strength  value but doenot make form invalid.

For creating custom validator  you can follow this link
[Custom validator Example](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-custom-validators-in-angular)

Comment: Ok then it was my bad. Just created another customValidator and it works. Didn't used the strength value at all but it works.